# How do I find this component's footprint?

Tags: components, footprint

I have this socket adapter that I need to make a footprint for (the header pin part), but I can't find the mechanical drawing anywhere:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/133771173193?hash=item1f25621d49:g:VyEAAOSwUU9hlrXq

Comment: First rule: No datasheet = no buy. At least in your case you can just look at the footprint and know what it is though since it follows common standards.

Comment: I figured I could find out the pitch of the header pins (maybe 1.27mm), but the width between header rows is difficult for me to figure out.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the header pins will be on 0.1 inch (2.54 mm) centers, so the thing can plug into a normal DIP socket.  The sockets on traditional DIP programmers can accept pin row spacing of 0.3 to 0.6 inch, so that adaptor will have row spacing in that range - from the illustration, the spacing will be something less than 0.6 inch.

Comment: Buy part first, measure, then finalize the PCB route. As @PeterBennett said, the width is likely to be either 0.3 or 0.6, so you could place both sets of mount holes (one side only) at those distances to make it universal to reduce the risk.